# In Sitecore how do you approve or reject a deleted item?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

It seems like when you delete an item it happens right away without going through workflow or anything.  Is that right?  Additions and edits I understand.  But is there anyway to "mark an item for deletion" so that the next time there is a publish it will be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following blog post from John West -

["Manage Publication of Deletions with the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS"](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/09/Manage-Publication-of-Deletions-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to publish the parent item. This will publish the deleted status of child items but won't publish changes to sub items. Unfortunately I can't find any documentation confirming this but it seems to work for me…

I don't know how to reject deletions, but they should be visible in the Recycle Bin and can be restored from there (go into the SiteCore shell, click the sitecore menu and select Recycle Bin).